# How to draw a chart from Data in Model MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

For a project that i want to build some feature , i need to have a view with chart on a web page.

M**y project is an MVC ASP.net c# who works with the Entity Framework .** 
All the part are sucessfully created so no major bug here.
I already tried to use C3.js ( This link : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc5-generate-bar-chart-using-javascript-c3-chart-library-and-entity-f/ ) and read a lot about other opportunities like Google Chart , Charts .js and so on but i really want to use C3.js .

*I don't fully understand all the code so i tried to adapt it but no chart :(
( The view sucessfully launch but nothing )*

For the table that i want to render , here's the sql create code :

```
USE [garagenew]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Fuel]    Script Date: 17-04-19 13:07:23 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Fuel](
    [RECID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [FichePrise] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DatePrise] [datetime] NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [VehicleId] [nvarchar](13) NULL,
    [BadgeNumber] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Kilometer] [float] NULL,
    [Hour] [int] NULL,
    [Volume] [float] NULL,
    [CuveName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [BornName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ProductName] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [RUNDATE] [date] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Fuel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [RECID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I tried this controller :

```
    using ConsulFru.Models;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    namespace ConsulFru.Controllers
    {
        public class ChartController : Controller
        {
            // GET: Chart  
            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }
            public ActionResult BarChart()
            {
                bdfru entities = new bdfru();
                return Json(entities.Fuel.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
    }
```

and this view :

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    }
    <br />
    <div id="Barchart"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Chart/BarChart",
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    successFunc(response);
                },
            });

            function successFunc(jsondata) {
                var chart = c3.generate({
                    bindto: '#Barchart',
                    data: {
                        json: jsondata,
                        keys: {
                            value: ['BadgeNumber','Kilometer'],
                        },
                        columns: ['BadgeNumber', 'Kilometer'],
                        type: 'bar',
                        groups: [
                            ['BadgeNumber', 'Kilometer'],
                        ]
                    },
                    color: {
                        pattern: ['#1f77b4', '#aec7e8', '#ff7f0e', '#ffbb78', '#2ca02c', '#98df8a', '#d62728', '#ff9896', '#9467bd', '#c5b0d5', '#8c564b', '#c49c94', '#e377c2', '#f7b6d2', '#7f7f7f', '#c7c7c7', '#bcbd22', '#dbdb8d', '#17becf', '#9edae5']
                    },
                });
            }
        });

    </script>
```

I expect to draw some chart with this table first and after , adapt the code so i can do it with whatever i want .

Can someone Help Me?

Comment: You don't draw charts with a database, that's just a data source. You could use an array with hard-coded values instead. The important part is hitting the `/Chart/BarChart` url to retrieve that data and chart it. You could (should?) just ignore everything in that article up to `Generate a Chart Controller`. In that controller, create and return an array instead of calling EF, with `return JSON(myArray)`.

Comment: Once you get the chart to work, you can change the array objects to match those you want and update the scripts to use the new properties. Only once you get that working should you try to use EF to load those objects from the database. Divide and conquer

Comment: I don't understand all that you said . :/ 

I added some precision to the post .